# Weak differentiability vs differentiability almost everywhere

Tags: functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions, weak-derivatives

Is there any relation between weak differentiability and differentiability almost everywhere? Does one imply the other?
Does Lipschitz continuity imply both of them?
Thank you.